# Como funciona os SIDs dos usuários?

Tags: c#, autenticação, identificador

Preciso implementar um sistema de autenticação escrito em C#.NET baseado em usuários do **Windows**, portanto ele irá ser autenticado de acordo com alguma identificação **única** dos usuários.

O problema, é que a única identificação viável que encontrei que possa representar um usuário é o SID, mas tenho algumas pequenas dúvidas sobre o mesmo:

- Um SID de um usuário conectado na conta da Microsoft Live será o mesmo SID se estiver conectado em outras máquinas?
- Um SID é gerado de forma aleatória para um usuário local?
- Se a primeira pergunta for não, e o SID é apenas um *identificador do usuário local para a máquina*, como posso obter uma identificação cujo **seja única para uma conta da Microsoft Live, e aleatória para uma conta local?**

É este o código usado para obter o SID do usuário **que está "logado" na máquina**:

```
WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
SecurityIdentifier sid = user.User;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Um SID de um usuário conectado na conta da Microsoft Live será o mesmo
>   SID se estiver conectado em outras máquinas?

Sim. Para provar isso existe até um comando que lhe permite buscar o SID de um utilizador windows:

```
wmic useraccount where name="user" get sid
```

[Fonte](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-find-a-users-security-identifier-sid-in-windows-2625149)

Eu tentei executar este comando para um utilizador que nunca se logou no meu computador e retornou-me um SID.

> Um SID é gerado de forma aleatória para um usuário local?

Nao faco a minima ideia.

Caso tenha problemas pode sempre recorrer á propriedade `Name` do objeto `WindowsIdentity`

```
WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
user.Name
```